# Youtube Flash Playlist player is not loading

Tags: youtube-api

I hope someone from youtube is looking in

The playlist flash player from youtube is only buffering but not loading the thumb

To see the problem http://www.youtube.com/embed/?listType=search&list=webm

This occurs only in the flash player not in the html5 version

Also the params doesn't seem to work

Reported here ( http://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=5024 ) but knowbody is looking

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
Go to **chrome://plugins** in the address bar.

Disable *Google\Chrome\Application{version}\PepperFlash\pepflashplayer.dll*

After this it should be started using Flash Player from Adobe, not the build one.